# RuntimeError: This event loop is already running, 'Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running')

Tags: python, aiohttp, pytest-aiohttp

Below is a minimal reproducible example.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from database_utils import connect_to_database
from pytdx.hq import TdxHq_API
api = TdxHq_API()
api.connect('119.147.212.81', 7709)



async def execute_main(conn, c):
   

    try:
        c.execute("SELECT stockCode, shsz FROM stocks")
        rows = c.fetchall()
        column_names = [description[0] for description in c.description]
        results = [dict(zip(column_names, row)) for row in rows]

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            tasks = []
            for result in results:
                stock_code = result['stockCode'].strip()
                market = result['shsz']
                tasks.append(fetch_quote(session, api, market, stock_code, conn, c))

            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

    api.disconnect()
    print("Execution completed.")

# Establish a connection to the database
conn, c = connect_to_database()

# Run the main function
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(execute_main(conn, c))



 597 def _check_running(self):
    598     if self.is_running():
--> 599         raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
    600     if events._get_running_loop() is not None:
    601         raise RuntimeError(
    602             'Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running')
```

When I use

```
asyncio.run(execute_main(conn, c))
```

I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\Steven\my-app\management\real.time.price2.py:52
     49 conn, c = connect_to_database()
     51 # Run the main function
---> 52 asyncio.run(execute_main(conn, c))

File c:\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py:190, in run(main, debug, loop_factory)
    161 """Execute the coroutine and return the result.
    162 
    163 This function runs the passed coroutine, taking care of
   (...)
    186     asyncio.run(main())
    187 """
    188 if events._get_running_loop() is not None:
    189     # fail fast with short traceback
--> 190     raise RuntimeError(
    191         "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop")
    193 with Runner(debug=debug, loop_factory=loop_factory) as runner:
    194     return runner.run(main)

RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

The current running event loop is: <_WindowsSelectorEventLoop running=True closed=False debug=False>
```

Comment: What's the contents of `connect_to_database()`? Would be nice with a [mre].

Comment: import sqlite3

def connect_to_database():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/SQLite/pythonstock/database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    return conn, c

Comment: My guess is that you're running this module within something else which has an event loop. Otherwise, start removing code that runs before that line until you can get the function to atleast start, then you can figure out what is running an event loop already.

Comment: The current running event loop is: <_WindowsSelectorEventLoop running=True closed=False debug=False>

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if it had an [mcve] -- code that we can copy and run locally to reproduce the problem.